# How to implement BQL Bloomberg excel formula to python API (blpapi)?

Tags: bloomberg, blpapi

Is there a way to implement BQL using python API or even any language`s API?

Comment: You cannot just change the entire question like that. I rolled back your edits. If you want to ask a new question, click the “Ask Question” button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask for access to BQNT. There is currently no publicly available interface to the BQL Excel formula from any programming language.

Comment: There is currently no publicly available interface to access BQL outside of BQNT. You would have to suggest it to them as an enhancement. To my knowledge from recent experience it's unlikely to come out any time soon...