# How to pull out the list of active German government bonds using xbbg?

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I would like to pull out the list of ISINs for existing active german government bonds using the xbbg library but I couldn't find a way to do so.

The Bloomberg ticker used to access the universe in Bloomberg is DBR Govt. The bql query in excel would be the following:

```
=@BQL.Query("get(ID_ISIN) for(filter(bondsUniv('Active'),TICKER==DBR))";"cols=2;rows=49")
```

I tried a few things:

1)

```
from xbbg import blp
query = blp.bdib(ticker='DBR Govt', dt=date.today()).tail()
```

based on example for equities, but I get an error `KeyError: 'Cannot find exchange info for DBR Govt'`.

or, for instance,

2)

```
from xbbg import blp
query = blp.bdp(tickers='DBR Govt', flds=['ID_ISIN'])
```

but this produces an empty dataframe.
Does anyone have any idea what should I do?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no officially published api for BQL via Python.

There are some workarounds in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68858073/how-to-use-the-bql-bloomberg-excel-formula-for-python-api-xbbg-or-blpapi/69014472#69014472).

However, in this instance you can retrieve a list of current Bunds via the `//blp/instruments` service in the DAPI ... with a bit of work. The information on this service is buried on page 49 in the [Bloomberg API reference](https://data.bloomberglp.com/professional/sites/10/2017/03/BLPAPI-Core-Developer-Guide.pdf).

The `xbbg` package does not support this explicitly, but you can use its excellent framework for any DAPI request. Unfortunately I have not found a way to filter the returned list upfront for active bonds: the DAPI function returns every Bund, whether matured or not. However you can do a second `bdp` query for the bond maturities and filter on that:

```
from xbbg.core import conn,process
from xbbg import blp
from datetime import date

def allGovts(ticker): #Return all govts with the given ticker, matured or not
    req = process.create_request(service='//blp/instruments',request='govtListRequest')
    req.set('ticker',ticker)
    req.set('partialMatch',False)
    req.set('maxResults',1000)
        
    def _process_instruments(msg): #Process the response
        for elt in msg.asElement().getElement('results').values():
            yield elt.getElementAsString('parseky')
    
    conn.send_request(request=req)
    return process.rec_events(func=_process_instruments)

def liveGovts(ticker): #Just return 'live' bonds, ordered by maturity
    tdy = date.today()
    dfAll = blp.bdp([g for g in allGovts(ticker)],['id_isin','maturity'])
    return dfAll[ dfAll['maturity'] > tdy ].sort_values('maturity')

print(liveGovts('DBR'))
```

with the result:

```
                    id_isin    maturity
EJ506625 Corp  DE0001102309  2023-02-15
EJ677578 Corp  DE0001102317  2023-05-15
EJ815896 Corp  DE0001102325  2023-08-15
...
ZR097974 Corp  DE0001102481  2050-08-15
BR246981 Corp  DE0001102572  2052-08-15
BY899086 Corp  DE0001102614  2053-08-15
```

Of course, you may want other additional properties of the bonds, so you can amend the `bdp` call to include those extra fields.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much for an extensive answer, I didn't know about the //blp/instruments service indeed.